# How to use new San Francisco font in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, fonts, ios9

Before **iOS 9** to reference fonts we used `fontWithName` of `UIFont`:

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:18]
```

Now we're moving to iOS 9. How to reference a new **San Francisco font** in the same way?

We can use it with `systemFontOfSize` of `UIFont`, but how to reference styles other than regular? For example, how to use **San Francisco Medium** or **San Francisco Light** fonts?

Comment: This kind of sounds like a thing that is going to be in the iOS9 developer docs. Have you looked there yet? (If so, and it's not in there, that's worth putting in your answer. If not, step one is to look there)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

In iOS 9 it is the system font, so you could do:

```
let font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18)
```

You *can* use the font name directly, but I don't think this is safe:

```
let font = UIFont(name: ".SFUIText-Medium", size: 18)!
```

You can also create the font with [specific weight](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFontDescriptor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Font_Weights), like so:

```
let font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18, weight: UIFontWeightMedium)
```

or

```
let font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18, weight: UIFontWeightLight)
```

Comment: Any official ways to use Medium or Light?

Comment: Just to emphasize: MirekE is correct, it is not safe to use `.SFUIText-Medium` or any other exact San Fransisco name. Apple has stated that those names are private and subject to change. They want you to use the system font methods built into `UIFont` and `NSFont`, specifically because they reserve the right to modify what exactly the system font is, depending on the user's situation.

Comment: Of course, if you _really_ need a font name, `let fontName = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18, weight: UIFontWeightLight).fontName` , so that if the private name changes, you automatically retrieve the right one.

Comment: i'm using SF weightlight font on iOS 9 to make a custom keyboard, but the trouble is it looks lighter than default font. i've tried to switch regular and medium font, but it quite not like the text on default iOS keyboard?!

Comment: is there any way to use this font on a UIWebView?

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4**

```
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold)
```

Comment: Does this have a way to differentiate between `SFUIText` and `SFUIDisplay`?

Answer (score 2):

### Details

- Xcode Version 10.2.1 (10E1001), Swift 5

### Solution

```
import UIKit

extension UIFont {

    enum Font: String {
        case SFUIText = "SFUIText"
        case SFUIDisplay = "SFUIDisplay"
    }

    private static func name(of weight: UIFont.Weight) -> String? {
        switch weight {
            case .ultraLight: return "UltraLight"
            case .thin: return "Thin"
            case .light: return "Light"
            case .regular: return nil
            case .medium: return "Medium"
            case .semibold: return "Semibold"
            case .bold: return "Bold"
            case .heavy: return "Heavy"
            case .black: return "Black"
            default: return nil
        }
    }

    convenience init?(font: Font, weight: UIFont.Weight, size: CGFloat) {
        var fontName = ".\(font.rawValue)"
        if let weightName = UIFont.name(of: weight) { fontName += "-\(weightName)" }
        self.init(name: fontName, size: size)
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
guard let font = UIFont(font: .SFUIText, weight: .light, size: 14) else { return }

// ...

let font = UIFont(font: .SFUIDisplay, weight: .bold, size: 17)!
```