# Why am I getting a "Value of optional type UIFont not unwrapped", but unwrapping gives "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional"?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, uifont, forced-unwrapping

```
func initializePickerViewProperties() {
    let font = UIFont (name: "SanFranciscoDisplay-Regular", size: 30.0)
    let highlightedFont = UIFont (name: "SanFranciscoDisplay-Bold", size: 35.0)
    pickerView.font = font!
    pickerView.highlightedFont = highlightedFont!
}
```

fairly simple, the pickerView in question is an [AKPickerView](https://github.com/Akkyie/AKPickerView-Swift)

If I remove the forced unwrapping I get a compiler error. "Value of optional type UIFont not unwrapped, did you mean to use "!" or "?"?"

However, when I force unwrap it, I get a runtime error. "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use new San Francisco font in iOS 9?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369711/how-to-use-new-san-francisco-font-in-ios-9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Means your fonts are not initialized properly and give `nil`. You should safely unwrap them:

```
func initializePickerViewProperties() {
    if let font = UIFont (name: "SanFranciscoDisplay-Regular", size: 30.0),
        let highlightedFont = UIFont (name: "SanFranciscoDisplay-Bold", size: 35.0) {
        pickerView.font = font
        pickerView.highlightedFont = highlightedFont
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it looks like they are never successfully unwrapped, and I never enter the IF. Any idea why this might be? Perhaps incorrect Font name?

Comment: Yes, but if you're interested by the proper way to use the San Francisco system font, and not just *any font but the system one*, follow the duplicate link I posted under the question...

Answer (score 5):

Try printing all available fonts, and check the spelling of your fontname

```
 for fontfamily in UIFont.familyNames{
        for fontname in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: fontfamily){
            print(fontname)
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what if your font name is not provided?

Answer (score 0):

You must first add your **custom font** inside your **Info.plist**.

To look for the **Info.plist** file:

1. Make sure you have imported your custom font onto your project.
2. Click the blue icon on the topmost part of your project navigator--the project itself.
3. Go to the **Info** tab.
4. Look for **Fonts provided by application**.
5. Then, click the **plus icon** to add a new key-value pair to our Info.plist.
6. Add the exact file name of the font you imported, *including the file extension*.

I solved mine using this. Hope it works for you as well.