# In Xamarin Forms how can I set the font of a label to Medium (System font)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to use SF Pro (iOS) and Roboto (Android) which are the system fonts. Both have medium but I cannot see any way to set these for a label.

I think I might need a Label custom renderer and would appreciate any advice / suggestions.

Here are some references:

https://qiita.com/aqubi/items/3a1e668f4f78d4ad0db7

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/97446/set-font-weight-on-label

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8035

Comment: Is the issue only for iOS? Also, how are you trying to set the SemiBold family?

Comment: I would like to know how to set for both iOS and Android.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start with Android - you can't set `Roboto` font to `semi-bold`, since the font doesn't support this weight. Link for reference - [Roboto - Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto).

For iOS, San Francisco supports this font weight. Since you are using the built-in system fonts, simply setting the value to `.SFUIText-Semibold` should do the trick.

**UPDATE**

Due to the updated nature of the question, we can have 2 approaches here for iOS. The warning message, that you are getting, says it all:

> CoreText note: Client requested name ".SFUIText-Medium", it will get TimesNewRomanPSMT rather than the intended font. All system UI font access should be through proper APIs such as CTFontCreateUIFontForLanguage() or +[UIFont systemFontOfSize:].

This means that in our render, we can set the font like this:

```cs
Control.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(17, UIFontWeight.Medium);
```

The warning message also says that it can be achieved with `CTFont` like so:

```cs
new CTFont(".SFUIText-Medium", 17);
```

For iOS, it is preferrable to use the first approach with `SystemFontOfSize`.

NB: Keep in mind that this may not remove the warning message, since very often they are caused from 3rd-party packages, which are still refering to an old Forms version, or are setting the font incorrectly. If this happens, inspect your packages and raise an issue, if necessary. You can take a look at the official commit that fixed this ([link](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/8418/files/68e47d3e963c9cab01bc59bd53434e2d35ee20d7)). As you can see, they are splitting the string that you've provided and taking the last part. If the last part can be converter to [UIFontWeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uifontweight?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12), they are setting the font the same way as I have just described. So, in the end, if you provide the font as `.SFUIText-Medium` in your shared project, it will have the same effect as explicitly refering to it in your custom renderer, because both approaches end up with the same code. Again, you'd want to check your 3rd-party libraries, if the warning persists.

Here's a screenshot with both results - setting the font in the shared project & setting it with a renderer:
[image: iOS]

For Android you can again set the font in a renderer. Here, you'll need a custom style for this one. In your Android project, create a new style in `Resources/values/styles.xml` like this:

```xml
<style name="FontRobotoMedium">
  <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">#333333</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
</style>
```

You can customize a lot here, but for this sample, I have simply addded the family, size & color.

Then, in your renderer, simply change the control's `TextAppearance`:

```cs
Control.SetTextAppearance(Resource.Style.FontRobotoMedium);
```

Keep in mind that this can also be achieved without any renderers utilising the power of the system built-in fonts like this:

```xml
<Label FontFamily="sans-serif-medium" />
```

For reference of Android's system fonts, see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/data/fonts/fonts.xml).

NB: Keep in mind that Android system fonts are also a subject to a frequent change, so it is again not advisable to use the fonts like this. There's a huge warning at the beginning of `fonts.xml` file that I have given a reference to:

> WARNING: Parsing of this file by third-party apps is not supported. The
> file, and the font files it refers to, will be renamed and/or moved out
> from their respective location in the next Android release, and/or the
> format or syntax of the file may change significantly. If you parse this
> file for information about system fonts, do it at your own risk. Your
> application will almost certainly break with the next major Android
> release.

Here's a screenshot with both results - setting the font in the shared project & setting it with a renderer:
[image: android]
NOTE: The fonts defer a bit due to a slight difference in the text padding, which can be adjusted in the style like this:

```xml
<item name="android:padding">1dip</item>
```

To sum up, what you can do with a custom renderer, can also be done in the shared project. Under all of the code, the team from Xamarin is doing it very similar (if not the same), as the code from the custom renderer. Don't expect all of the warnings to be gone, since if any 3rd-party library hasn't ungraded to latest forms, or is using the system fonts incorrectly, the warnings will still appear.

Again, it is really not a good practice to try to use the system fonts. They are reserved (and in the case of iOS - hidden behind a dot (.) name) for a reason. In one or two updates, the font may changed and will break the appearance of your app. If you don't have any explicit reason to not import the font files, I'd strongly suggest that you import the font files are refer to them for their families. If you still want to use the system fonts, you can achieve this without any renderers. For iOS simply set the family to `.SFUIText-Medium` and for Android - to `sans-serif-medium` (both in your shared project).

**UPDATE 2**

Let's say that you'll set the family as an enum in your shared project. The enum can look like this:

```cs
public enum FontFamilyType
{
    Light,
    Regular,
    Medium
}
```

You can add one additional property in your `CustomLabel` wrapper - e.g.

```cs
public FontFamilyType FontFamilyType { get; set; }
```

You can make it bindable property, if necessary.

Here are 2 renderers that take change the font to Regular, Light & Medium. For iOS:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomLabel), typeof(CustomLabelRenderer))]
namespace FontRenderers.iOS
{
    public class CustomLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null && Element != null)
            {
                UIFont font;

                switch (Element.FontFamilyType)
                {
                    case FontFamilyType.Light:
                        font= UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(18, UIFontWeight.Light);
                        break;
                    case FontFamilyType.Regular:
                        font= UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(18, UIFontWeight.Regular);
                        break;
                    case FontFamilyType.Medium:
                        font= UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(18, UIFontWeight.Medium);
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                }

                Control.Font = font;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I have given the example with all of the 3 requested font families. You can switch them however you'd like - manually, checking some parameters, etc.

For Android:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomLabel), typeof(CustomLabelRenderer))]
namespace FontRenderer.Droid
{
    public class CustomLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        public CustomLabelRenderer(Context context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            int fontFamilyResId;

            switch (Element.FontFamilyType)
            {
                case FontFamilyType.Light:
                    fontFamilyResId = Resource.Style.FontRobotoLight;
                    break;
                case FontFamilyType.Regular:
                    fontFamilyResId = Resource.Style.FontRobotoRegular;
                    break;
                case FontFamilyType.Medium:
                    fontFamilyResId = Resource.Style.FontRobotoMedium;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }


            Control.SetTextAppearance(fontFamilyResId);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, for Android you'll need 2 more styles (for the light & regular families). In `styles.xml` add these 2 styles:

```xml
<style name="FontRobotoLight">
  <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
</style>

<style name="FontRobotoRegular">
  <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Apologies setting to Medium

Comment: setting the value to .SFUIText-Semibold works but comes up with a warning message so I  would like to explore setting in a Label Custom Renderer.  Tomorrow I will open a bounty for that as I think it would be a good chance for others to see how the renderers could be coded up.

Comment: I'll research and come back with more info.

Comment: Thanks Mihail. Looking forward to a custom renderer solution for iOS and Android.  I'm hopeful there's one out there. Have a good night.

Comment: Thanks, can you give an example of two small label renderers that would take a binding of <  FontWeight = "Light", FontWeight = "Regular" and FontWeight = "Medium" If you could do that then I think that might be enough for to me achieve the needed functionality and I could award the answer to you.

Comment: I will check your answer tomorrow and expect to accept.  Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: Hello, "In styles.xml add these 2 styles" - Do I not need to add the third style for FontRobotoRegular ?

Comment: You need to end up with 3 styles in total - regular, light & medium.

Comment: Thanks, Mihail. I will award you the answer as you gave me both and iOS and Android custom renderer.

Comment: @Alan2 why have you accepted my answer, but you gave the bounty to Jack's answer?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want? It is not recommend to use the name of font as it is private and may change in the future.

Here is the code for customLabel:

```
public class customLabel : Label{

    public int myFont { get; set; }
}
```

And in Xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

    <app307:customLabel Text="testText" myFont="15"
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

Here is the code of Renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(customLabel), typeof(MyLabelRenderer))]
namespace App307.iOS
{
    public class MyLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            int fontSize = 18;

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                customLabel label = e.NewElement as customLabel;

                fontSize = label.myFont;
            }

            if (Control != null)
            {
       
                UIFont font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(fontSize, UIFontWeight.Medium);
                Control.Font = font;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Refer: [use new San Francisco font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369711/how-to-use-new-san-francisco-font-in-ios-9)

Comment: For this solution what if I had specified a different font size?  For example font-size=15 or font-size=20.  Your solution for iOS only works for the one size.

Comment: @Alan2 See my updated answer, add a myFont  property in custom label and then you can get it in the renderer.